# SortedSet<string> Linq .Except with Comparer strangeness

Tags: c#, linq, sortedset, .net-4.6

I'm using .NET 4.6 and I experienced serious strangeness. I'm trying to get an IEnumerable of all values from a sorted set that are NOT the case-insensitive equivalent of the passed in IEnumerable. From what I understand, that is the job of Except.

I have a class, CaseInsensitiveComparer which is implemented like so:

```
public class CaseInsensitiveComparer : IComparer<string>, IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    public static CaseInsensitiveComparer Instance { get; private set; }
    static CaseInsensitiveComparer()
    {
        Instance = new CaseInsensitiveComparer();
    }

    public int Compare(string a, string b)
    {
        var ret = string.Compare(a, b, true);
        return ret;
    }

    public bool Equals(string a, string b)
    {
        return Compare(a, b) == 0;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string a)
    {
        return a.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

I use it like this:

```
    public void DotNetWeirdness()
    {
        var a = new SortedSet<string>();
        a.Add("A");
        var b = a.Except(new string[] { "a" }, CaseInsensitiveComparer.Instance);
    }
```

The value of b is an IEnumerable containing A. Since I'm asking for all values in SortedSet except for a/A, shouldn't I have an empty set as the result? I'm quite confused by this.

Thanks!

Comment: You did not write `GetHashCode` to return the same value for `a` and `A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're not overriding `GetHashCode`. `"A".GetHashCode()` returns a different value from `"a".GetHashCode()`.

A quick way to fix this is to change the `GetHashCode` function to this:

```
public int GetHashCode(string a)
{
    return a.ToLower().GetHashCode();
}
```

Also, do you know about `StringComparer`? You can change your code to this:

```
var b = a.Except(new string[] { "a" }, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

And not have to worry about implementing your own comparer

Comment: That fixed it exactly. Also, thank you very much for the StringComparer. I think I read about it at one point and either forgot about it, or it wouldn't work for some other code in the system or something. Either way, thank you very much for the fix and the insight!